# VBA Code to cycle through worksheets starting with a specific sheet (index 3)

Tags: vba, excel

I need to cycle through sheets of index 3 tip last sheet and run a code. I tried something like this but its doesn't work.

```
If (ws.sheetIndex > 2) Then
        With ws
            'code goes here
        End With
End If
```

I did a search but don't find a solution to this problem. Help would be much appreciated.

I also tried:

```
Dim i As Long, lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Windows("Book1").Activate

With ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = .Worksheets("index")
    For i = 3 To 10
        'code goes here
    Next i


End With
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following, which iterates over all worksheets in your workbook and only "acts" for worksheets with index 3 or above.

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet

For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If sheet.Index > 2 Then
    ' Do your thing with each "sheet" object, e.g.:
    sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "hi"
  End If
Next
```

Note that this doesn't put a hard limit on the number of sheets you have (10 or whatever), as it will work with any number of worksheets in your active workbook.

---

**EDIT**

If you want the code to run on worksheets with names `"Sheet" + i` (where `i` is an index number from 3 onwards), then the following should help:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

For i = 3 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
  If sheet.Name = "Sheet" & i Then
    ' Do your thing with each "sheet" object, e.g.:
    sheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "hi"
  End If
Next i
```

Of course, this means that the names of your worksheets need to always follow this pattern, so it's not best practice. However, if you're sure the names are going to stay like this, then it should work well for you.

Comment: @user3720702: Check out my update and run the code, then see how many worksheets have the word "hi" in the cell A1. How many worksheets are there in your workbook and what are they called? Do you want any code to run on worksheets with names "Sheet" + an index number from 3 onwards?

Comment: Your code works. I initially forgot to include this new code within another loop. No it's importing the sheets and running the code you suggested to all the sheets with index > 2. Works beautifully! Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the user can reorder the sheets in the Worksheets Collection, so it is better to refer to the sheets by CodeName (which the user cannot change), and exclude by CodeName the sheets to be skipped, as here:

```
Public Sub TestLoop()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim ws As Worksheet, s As String
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.CodeName <> "Sheet2" Then
            s = s & vbNewLine & ws.CodeName
        End If
    Next ws

    s = "WorksheetList (except Sheet2:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & s

    MsgBox s, vbOKOnly, "Test"
EndSUb:
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Resume EndSUb
End Sub
```

If I drag Sheet 3 to precede Sheet1, the MsgBox outputs:

```
WorksheetList (except Sheet2:

Sheet3
Sheet1
```

Comment: Or (far) better, refer to them by codename, unless they're created at runtime. In that case assign them to variables when they're created and refer to those.

Comment: @DougGlancy: Of course one expects the permanent sheets to have been given meaningful names. What would you have had me call three empty sheets in a quick test case.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear. I'm referring to the fact that users can change sheet names. Bacause of that, it's better to refer to the `Worksheet.Codename` property, which the user can't change. Or if the sheets are created at runtime, creating worksheet variables and referring to those is similarly foolproof. Here's a link on `Codename`: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RenameProblems.aspx.

Comment: @DougGlancy: Thank you; got it now. It's a good day when I learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

Try excluding first and second sheet using name:

```
Public Sub Sheets3andUp()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nameOfSheet1 As String
Dim nameOfSheet2 As String

nameOfSheet1 = "Sheet1"
nameOfSheet2 = "Sheet2"

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> nameOfSheet1 And ws.Name <> nameOfSheet2 Then
        'Code goes here
        Debug.Print ws.Name
    End If
Next ws
```

End Sub